# Why did the Matthias character on Wasteland 2 have a portrait of Pope Clement V

Tags: wasteland-2, wasteland-2-directors-cut, wasteland

I was reading about history, then I realized that the portrait of the Matthias character is the same that a painting of the pope Clement V. There is a reason for that? Its a wink or something like that?

https://static.educalingo.com/img/en/800/pope-clement-v.jpg

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/wasteland_gamepedia/images/3/32/Wl2_portrait_Matthias.tex.png/revision/latest?cb=20140922194405